# Matlab: How do i tell if the ode is stiff or not?

Tags: matlab, ode

How do i check if the ode is stiff or not? Unfortunately, my problem is large so I cannot run different ode matlab solvers and compare their finish time. I hope I can tell from the ode itself directly. What are some characteristics of a stiff ode?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiff_equation for some hints. It's difficult to say in general.

Comment: See the table [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/choose-an-ode-solver.html#bu3n5rf-1).

Comment: I think this question is unsuited for stackoverflow, because it is about maths instead of programming.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is extremly hard to tell if the ode is stiff or not without running some integration methods especially if it's a large problem.

You could try to reduce the problem to a simpler one, e.g. Taylor-expansion and only taking the first 2 or 3 terms into consideration. Solving this problem **could** give you a hint whether your problem is stiff or not.

Note that I assumed your problem would be continous. Then according to Weierstraß' approximation theorem a series of polynomials (your Taylor expansion) would converge uniformly to your problem. This means if the problem with taylor series is stiff your original problem might be too.